# What is embodiment of death associated with ?

Tags: super-powers

I wanted to know what is embodiment of death power associated with ? like it associated with decay, rot.

Comment: I think death is associated with order. Without death chaos will spread everywhere.

Comment: It's your magic system; you can define it however you want. So long as you're clear, it doesn't matter what anyone else's opinion is on the subject.

Comment: Death is not magic it divine?

Answer (score 1):

How death is regarded is mostly culture dependent, some cultures see death as the final end and do indeed associate it with rot and decay, but in some cultures (like Hinduism on earth) it's merely part of a cycle as the deceased reincarnates according to the Hindus.